# Auto-entering Password In Sn.exe

Tags: c#, signing, sn.exe

I need to create post build event to perform the following:

```
sn -i MyKey.pfx MyKeyContainerName
tlbimp $(ConfigurationName)\MyCom.tlb /out:$(ConfigurationName)\NETMyCom.dll /keycontainer:MyKeyContainerName
sn -d MyKeyContainerName
```

When the Visual Studio executes the 1st statement it requires a password and waits until the user specifies it and fails.

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong
>   Name Utility Version 2.0.50727.42
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Enter the password for the PKCS#12 key
>   file: Failed to parse the PKCS#12 
>   blob in mykey.pfx -- The handle is
>   invalid.

I tried to specify the password using sn command line arguments, but I could not see a way to do it.

Please help.

Regards,
Hilmi.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use Visual Studio's own key-signing feature? (Check the Properties for the project.)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, no approach mentioned here worked for me. I have to register couple pfxs in a docker container.

So I re-developed the
`sn.exe -i <infile> <container>` command in C# using the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8). The source and the app are on GitHub in
the [SnInstallPfx](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx) project.

The [SnInstallPfx](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx) app accepts a PFX key and its password. It computes the key container name (VS_KEY_*) automatically (borrowed from MSBuild source code) and installs it to the strong name CSP.

Usage:

```
SnInstallPfx.exe <pfx_infile> <pfx_password>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Most helpful.

Comment: Great, thx for feedback! I had updated cmdln args for the app. You can optionally pass the container name

Comment: You're literally a life savior.

Answer (score 3):

if like me, you are not using TFS or MSBUILD to build, then there are at least 2 other ways:

**a) run sn.exe from a script, and write the password to stdin**

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374645/sending-commands-to-stdin-and-sending-end-of-transmit-ctrld) for a C# example:

note: with the .NET4 version of sn.exe it seems to be impossible to execute it as external process (at least on Windows XP), and write the password to stdin (I tried with python + with C#, and sn.exe seems to just exit without waiting for password input).

**b) use sn.exe to re-sign the password, using a pfx that has already been installed.**

If you have already installed the pfx file, then you might know the container name (usually Visual Studio uses a name like VS_KEY_ABAB1234ABAB1234)

If, like me, you do not know or remember the container name, then just re-install the pfx file:

```
sn -i myPfxFile VS_KEY_ABAB1234ABAB1234
```

sn.exe will prompt you for a password, as it installs the certificate in the pfx file.

You can then make sn.exe re-sign your assembly, without any prompt for password:

```
sn -Rca myAssembly.dll myVSkey
```

The above can be used in a build script, as no interaction is required :-)

NB remember to check that the signing actually works:

```
sn -v myAssembly.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem come up today, with a C++ DLL that I use in a ClickOnce C# app.

I set up delay signing on the DLL, then used a post-build event to run SN like so:

```
ECHO <your-password-here> | sn.exe -R $(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)<path-to-pfx-file>
```

Gotta love the old-school batch methods. `ECHO <your-password-here>` prints your password, the pipe `|` pipes that output along to SN.exe, which takes the password.

You probably won't need delay signing and the -R switch like I did, but you get the idea.

EDIT: THIS PROBABLY NO LONGER WORKS - my answer was from 2013 and I was using VS2010 back then.

Comment: One other very important thing to know, that I only now just remembered: If you're putting this command in a batch file, and your password contains a `%` symbol, you need to use two of them. If your password is `super%cool%guy`, you need to use `super%%cool%%guy` in the batch file *only*.

Comment: The idea is great, but doesn't work on a batch file. `sn.exe` does not accept console input redirection and complains about it like this : `Console input may not be redirected for password entry`. Any ideas how to achieve this in a batch file?

Comment: I didn't have an issue with it. Can you post your batch file contents? (I did this a few years back and maybe the latest SN.exe doesn't allow it)

Comment: Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/seckin92/e37f5458db25f66d3d5b). Tried to set the password in a variable and pipe it into the `sn` command, but no luck :(

Comment: It may be changed in the later version of sn maybe - I tried with a pipe without batch file directly from the console it did not work either.

Comment: You're probably right. It worked on a much older SN.exe and they probably thought piping input was a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

I've been researching this for almost two days now. I tried older versions of sn.exe (going back as far as 2.0!), but I couldn't get the `echo PASSWORD |` trick to work.

In the end, I did this:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")

Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sn.exe " -ArgumentList "-i 
`"Certificate.pfx`" VS_KEY_XXXXXXX" -NoNewWindow -Wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("PASSWORDHERE~")
```

- `SendWait()` sends keys to the current activated window. Since we're starting `sn.exe` using `Start-Process` with the `-NoNewWindow` modifier, our window is already focussed.
- `~` is a special character, representing the ENTER button. `{ENTER}` is also possible, but that's for the Enter button near the numpad on your keyboard. Probably doesn't make any difference, but I just wanted to be sure.

Source I used: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx

I didn't need Visual Basic's `AppActivate()` in the end because of `-NoNewWindow`.

Update: Works even better with `-Wait` argument!

Comment: Same error than the cmd standard pipe, the input can't be redirected

Answer (score 1):

I needed this to be automatized and found this question. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943021/2135719) answer (many thanks @Thomas Rijsewijk) I've written my version of it:

```
# Start the sn.exe process
Start-Process $SnExePath -ArgumentList "-i $PfxCertificatePath $LocalContainerName" -NoNewWindow
# Wait for the process to start
Start-Sleep 2
# This workaround allows to forward the password to the standard input
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$($PfxCertificatePassword){ENTER}")
Start-Sleep 2
# This ENTER is to return from the sn.exe process
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Using the `-Wait` switch of the `Start-process` command did not solve the problem because the PS script was waiting the sn.exe process to terminate before forwarding the password to it.

Answer (score 1):

After a long investigation i can run sn.ex for various automated environments such as Azure devops. My code is here:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe 
Sleep 3
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Sleep 3
$WshShell.sendkeys(".\sn.exe -i  $PfxCertificatePath  VS_KEY_10D1C85C6387479B{Enter}");
Sleep 3;
$WshShell.sendkeys("**password**{Enter}");
Sleep 3;
$WshShell.sendkeys("{Enter}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WinAPI we can do it so:

```
Param(
    [string]  $Password ,
    [string] $CertFilePath 
)

function ExecuteCommand([string]$message)
{
    try{
    foreach ($char in [char[]]$message) {
    [void][WPIA.ConsoleUtils]::PostMessage($handle, [WPIA.ConsoleUtils]::WM_CHAR, [int]$char, 0) 
    }
    [void][WPIA.ConsoleUtils]::PostMessage($handle, [WPIA.ConsoleUtils]::WM_CHAR, 13, 0)
    Sleep 3
    }catch{
    }
}

Add-Type -Name ConsoleUtils -Namespace WPIA -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
public const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
'@

$Win32API = Add-Type -Name Funcs -Namespace Win32 -PassThru -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string  windowTitle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern uint GetLastError();
'@

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource
$publish.KeyFile=$CertFilePath
try
{
        $publish.Execute()
}
catch{
        $VsKey= [regex]::match($error[0].Exception,'VS_KEY_[A-F0-9]+').Value
        $VsKey =$VsKey -replace "`n|`r"
}
$quotedCertPath='"'+$CertFilePath+'"'
Write-Host 'VsKey='$VsKey

start cmd
$proc=Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*cmd*"}
$proc.MainWindowTitle
$handle = $proc.MainWindowHandle
'1:'+$handle
if($handle -eq 0){
    $handle=$Win32API::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe')
    '2:'+$handle
}   
if($handle -eq 0){
    $handle=$Win32API::FindWindow('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',       [IntPtr]::Zero)
    '3:'+$handle
}
if($handle -eq 0){
    $proc2 = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
    $proc2
    Get-Process -id $proc2.Id
    Sleep 3;
    $handle = (Get-Process -id $proc2.Id).MainWindowHandle
    $handle
    $proc.MainWindowHandle
    $proc.Refresh()
    Sleep 3;
    $proc.MainWindowHandle
}


Write-Host 'Handle='$handle

ExecuteCommand 'echo Starting > d:\a\1\s\Authenticode\log.txt'  
$SnCommand=[string]::Format(".\sn.exe -i {0} {1}",$quotedCertPath,$VsKey)
ExecuteCommand $SnCommand
ExecuteCommand $Password
```